# How get to simplify a symbolic and numeric mixed expression in Matlab

Tags: numeric, simplify, mixed, phrase

My finally result is:

(12*u)/5 + (12*4^(3/2))/13 - 1484/34

How to simplify this phrase to: 2.4000u - 36.2624 ?

and how to find u automatically? (u = 15.1093)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this must have been answered somewhere before. Also it can be found in the MATLAB documentation.

Use `simplify(expression)` and `solve(expression, u)`.

Answer (score 0):

simplify() and solve() don't work correctly:

> > a = (12*u)/5 + (12*4^(3/2))/13 - 1484/34

a =

[ (12*u)/5 - 8014/221, (12*u)/5 - 8014/221, (12*u)/5 - 8014/221, (12*u)/5 - 8014/221, (12*u)/5 - 8014/221]

> > simplify(a)

ans =

[ (12*u)/5 - 8014/221, (12*u)/5 - 8014/221, (12*u)/5 - 8014/221, (12*u)/5 - 8014/221, (12*u)/5 - 8014/221]

> > solve(a, u)
> >     Warning: 10 equations in 1 variables. 
> >     In C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\symengine.p>symengine at 54
> >       In mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.evalin at 96
> >       In mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.feval at 137
> >       In solve at 151 
> >     Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
> >     In solve at 160

ans =

[ empty sym ]